# Asp.net mvc restrict specific users to access folder content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to restrict users(except admin)   to access my folder images. For example the path is:

```
~/content/images/coverBeg.jpg
```

If the user navigates to  `domain/content/images/coverBeg.jpg`, he can see the file.
I've tryied different sort of things but none of them  worked for me. In web config file i've added :

```
    <location path="~/content/images">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

With no success. After that i've added a web config file to images folder and add those lines of code :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users ="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Neither this worked for me. Still everyone can access coverBeg.jpg file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because static content, like images, are served directly by IIS, not involving MVC pipeline.
To change that, you can do the following:

add

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

to `<system.webServer>` section of site's web.config. It will run MVC pipeline for every request, including static files - like css, js and images.

Then your config from above will work (I mean your 2nd approach).

Comment: Does it safe approach? There are files where users should pay to access, is it safe?

Comment: @ucnobiucnobi as safe as all the rest authentication/authorization mechanism. Basically, what it does - it says IIS to send there requests to MVC, and then standard MVC approach work.