# ASP.NET MVC: how to prevent unauthenticated user to directly GET images?

Tags: asp.net, image, model-view-controller

I have confidential images that I only want to show to authenticated users. On the  razor view, which is only accessible to authenticated users, I have

How do I prevent an unauthenticated user to bypass my razor view and directly request this photo through a HTTP GET?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are the images stored? In the same relative path or some external service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Attributes concept in mvc to accomplish your task.  Use `ActionFilterAttribute` and override `OnActionExecuting` method. For implementation you can visit following links.

[Asp.net mvc restrict specific users to access folder content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35382416/asp-net-mvc-restrict-specific-users-to-access-folder-content)

[ASP.NET MVC 4 intercept all incoming requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer, it has multiple ways to do this.

[Https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726848/asp-net-mvc-4-intercept-all-incoming-requests)

Answer (score 0):

You need to develop an http handler that checks for image extensions. See this article for how to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39158/Protect-Files-and-Folders-Using-HttpHandlers-in-AS